# Camerawesome: Camera Orientation Problem in My Flutter App

Tags: flutter, package, camera

I'm encountering a challenging issue with the camera orientation and distortion in my Flutter application while using the Camerawesome package. The problem I'm facing is that the camera view is rotated to the side and appears distorted when I try to capture images or record videos.
However, the strange thing is that when I select the captured image, it's not distorted and not rotate.

I've experimented with different configurations and settings within the Camerawesome package, including camera orientation settings, but none seem to resolve the issue.

```
final SensorConfig sensorConfig = SensorConfig.single(
    sensor: Sensor.position(SensorPosition.back),
    aspectRatio: CameraAspectRatios.ratio_16_9,
    flashMode: FlashMode.none, // Mode flash désactivé
    zoom: 0.0, // Pas de zoom
  );
```

```
CameraAwesomeBuilder.awesome(
  onMediaTap: (mediaCapture) {
    mediaCapture.captureRequest.when(
      single: (single) async {
        final File imageFile = File(single.file!.path);
        if (await imageFile.exists()) {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => StoryPostPage(imagePath: single.file!.path),
        ));
      } else {
        print("Erreur : le fichier n'existe pas.");
        }
     },
    multiple: (multiple) {
   },
   );
  },
  availableFilters: awesomePresetFiltersList, saveConfig: _buildSaveConfig(),
)
```

Image 1 :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSOaX.jpg
Image 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMkFU.jpg